# CPU memory for each program

Tags: assembly, cpu

I read that the CPU has a small amount of internal memory manipulated with registers. Is this memory unique for each program?

If there are a lot of programs running, can the CPU run out of this memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to [registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register).

Each CPU core only has one set of the registers. When the OS changes which process is running on the processor right now it saves the state of the registers somewhere is main RAM memory, and restores their value when beginning execution again.

You have to remember that programs on one CPU core are not executing in parallel, they are just being run a little and switched between so fast that it *seems* parallel to a human. That's why there can be only one set of registers.

Per the comments: read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a CPU has a single set of registers.

In order to use them over many processes ('programs' as you mention in your question), the OS saves the entire context of the current process in execution, whenever it switches to another process.

This procedure is called Context-Switch, and it includes saving the values of these registers.

When the OS switches back to a process, it reloads the registers with the previous values.

Comment: It doesn't involve saving the contents of memory. Things stay in physical memory, only the page tables change unless memory is running out, in which case paging happens.

Comment: Correct; Saving the entire memory contents onto the HD takes place only when the physical RAM is full, and it doesn't necessarily happen during the context switch of that specific process; answer revised

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking about [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), which all CPUs have a few KB to a few MB of near them, depending on the level (L1 cache, L2 cache, etc.). Ideally the CPU can use data in cache, since it is orders of magnitude faster to access than main memory. But because they are so small, they do indeed fill quickly. If the CPU can't find what it needs in one level of cache, it goes to the next level up. If it hasn't found the data in the highest level of cache available, it'll go out to main memory, swap that data into some portion of cache, and continue working.

There are various algorithms used to determine how to manage the data in cache, what to swap out, etc.

Comment: "There are only two hard problems in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things." - the OP isn't talking about cache though since he talked about registers

Comment: He asked about a "small amount of memory" and mentioned registers separately, which led me to believe that he's talking about cache.

Answer (score 0):

Actually on bigger CPUs like intel x86 the registers and also instructions implementation and internal CPU logic are stored in special high-speed memory, this is Microcode layer.

Look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode